# File uploading in CKEditor , bad url

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ckeditor

I have a problem uploading image and files using Ckeditor. After selecting an image, a bad file path is created. For example: 
base_path +"/files/upload"+"file_name"
One slash is missing, between "upload" and "file_name".

It works perfectly fine in my local environment, but when I push it to my remote server, the slash is missing.

I have checked the config files and everything seems to be just fine.

The server has ubuntu 14.04 and apache installed.

Comment: Well we cannot guess what you did wrong. You will need to provide code of how you do the upload and where you define the the different paths. A wild guess is that you could simply append "files/upload/" instead of "files/upload" since i supposed you filename will not start with a /

Comment: Thank you for answer. In my defalut.config.php file I define folder path "$folderPath = $app->basePath() . '/public/uploads/' ", 
in pluginconfg.php I define " $useruploadfolder = '../../../../uploads/' ",
also in filemanager.config.js " "fileRoot": "/" " .
I think is not problem with path configure because it works fine in my local Vagrant environment.

Comment: well it's most probably something wrong with your relative paths then. The $useruploadfolder seems to be something that might be wrong, however i can't tell without more information. You will need to actually post your code or more detailed landscape setup

Comment: Corrected and cleaned up the english